# how to perform release mode debugging in IAR

Tags: iar

When upgrading firmware from version 1 to version 2, there is a crash happening in Firmware.
The crash happens in release mode. How do i debug in release mode using IAR ?

Comment: *"How do i debug in release mode using IAR ?"* What is the actual problem that prevents you from debugging in release mode: Enabled code protection? Watchdog? Missing debugging symbols?

Comment: It is possible to enable debugging symbols in release mode but the accuracy of the debug info deteriorates quickly with increasing optimization level.